# How to figure out the information of dependency packages for missing frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Today I was adding a NuGet package `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` into my C# project. My C# project is targeting.Net framework v4.5. In NuGet package manager it shows the information of dependencies of the NuGet package as shown below:

[image]

There is no information corresponding to .Net Framework v4.5. So, how do I interpret this information if my project is targeting .Net Framework v4.5. Is this information missing or there is any default assumption in such cases may be *no dependencies*. Can someone share some information in this regard

**Note**: This question might look like a non-programming question but I got stuck even before writing a single line of code so asking it in this forum.

Comment: I believe the only way to look at first earlier version as that would be the one nuget picks. In your particular case,v4.0.

Comment: .NETFrameworks supports backwards compatible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility#backward-compatibility-and-the-net-framework-45. So nuget will install the dependence  "nearest"  backwards compatible framework v4.0. You can try to change your target framework to 4.6.1 or above, then install that package, the dependency `System.IO.Packaging (>= 4.4.0)` for .Net framework 4.6 will be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Frameworks are backwards compatible. Meaning if your project is targeting   v4.5, you can consume packages with lower versions, such as v4.0, v3.5.

NuGet's specialty is compatibility checking (if packages are authored correctly ofc) :)
NuGet knows the available frameworks are v3.5, v4.0, v4.6 and netstandard1.3. 
The "nearest" compatible framework with v4.5 is v4.0, so it'll pick the v4.0 assets when you install it.

So the answer, it has no dependencies in your case.

Please note that framework compatibility is not always apparent from just looking at the TFMs on nuget.org, there's different fallbacks that NuGet will attempt.

So really the best way to figure out what the dependencies are would be to install it in the project, since NuGet might need to resolve conflicts etc. if you have other dependencies.