# Erroneous dependency resolving for multi-targeting NuGet package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuspec

I am being confused by how dependencies are resolved when using a [group-based dependency specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependency-groups) in NuGet.

I have a Visual Studio project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1, with a NuGet dependency to a NuGet package (internal to my company):

This is in the `packages.config` file of my project:

`<package id="Name.Of.My.Package" version="2.0.65" targetFramework="net461" />`

And this is in the `.csproj` file:

`<Reference Include="Name.Of.My.Package, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Name.Of.My.Package.2.0.65\lib\net45\Name.Of.My.Package.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>`

That package is a multi-targeting package with a group-based dependency specification, which looks like this when I get it straight from the `.nuspec` file obtained by opening the `packages\Name.Of.My.Package.nupkg` file as an archive:

`<dependencies>
  <group>
    <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" />
  </group>
  <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0">
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" />
  </group>
</dependencies>`

And the `packages\Name.Of.My.Package\lib` folder contains:

- net40
- net45
- nestandard2.0

So my understanding here is that because my project is in net461, the reference should be added to the net45 version of my package (as seems to be the case if I look at the .csproj file), but more importantly that the only implicit dependency should be to Newtonsoft.

But this happens when I try to remove the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package in the package manager console:

`Uninstall-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168' with respect to project 'Name.Of.My.Project', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Resolving actions to uninstall package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168'
Uninstall-Package : Unable to uninstall 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168' because 'Name.Of.My.Package.2.0.65' depends on it.`

This is happening in the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Erroneous dependency resolving for multi-targeting NuGet package

This is the correct behavior of nuget. As we know, `.NET Frameworks` are backwards compatible. Meaning if your project is targeting `v4.6`, you can consume packages with lower versions, such as `v4.5`, `v4.0`.

> NuGet's specialty is compatibility checking (if packages are authored
>   correctly ofc) :) NuGet knows the available frameworks are v3.5, v4.0,
>   v4.6 and netstandard1.3. **The "nearest" compatible framework with v4.5
>   is v4.0, so it'll pick the v4.0 assets when you install it**.

Source: [How to figure out the information of dependency packages for missing frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335071/how-to-figure-out-the-information-of-dependency-packages-for-missing-frameworks)

So nuget will install the dependence "nearest" backwards compatible framework v4.6.1, in you case, the dependency `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` will also be installed.

That is the reason why you could not uninstall the package `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` when you have package `Name.Of.My.Package` installed.

For example, when you add the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.6` to the .net framework 4.6.1 project, nuget will also add the dependency `Newtonsoft.Json (>= 6.0.4)` under the .net framework 4.5:

[image]

[image]

Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility#backward-compatibility-and-the-net-framework-45) for some more details.